# Problem with drupal_execute for user_register and password field

Tags: php, forms, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

I am currently using the Drupal function drupal_execute to register users, however the password value seems to only record the first chracter when it saves in the DB.

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values'] = array(
    'name'          => strtolower(preg_replace("'\W'", "", $person->firstName) . $person->entityId),
    'mail'          => $person->emailPrimary,
    'pass'          => user_password(),
    'status'        => 1,
    'roles'         => $roles,
    'notify'        => 1,
);
drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state, NULL);
```

Printing out the form_state array reveals that the password is being set correctly, being 10 characters long.

Can anyone shed light as why only the first character of the pass value is saved to the db?

Thanks.
G

Answer (score 0):

Please check databse field for password

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Only the first character of the password gets saved to the table. I successfully logged in with one of these created accounts, using the username and the single character pwd it saved.